# NetSuite NS_Concat

Tags: oracle, netsuite

Need to be able to use NS_Concat and distinct with any method that will allow me to control the order of results returned.  I have ns_concat and distinct working but cannot figure out how to get an order by clause to work.  As an aside I have also gotten the listagg function to with an Order by clause but I can't use distinct with listagg.  Either function would work.  My goal is to get a results formula working where I concat distinct with an order.

Comment: Why don't you select distinct first, then use `listagg` on that result?

Comment: I tried that with a formula text minimum summary and it didn't work.